# Looking for a hinge that slides out first

Tags: doors, cabinets, hinges, hardware, pocket-door

I am trying to find a hinge that will come out about 2-4 inches and then open.  I can find slide mechanisms for furniture like a TV stand or armoire but they slide back once opened but I need one that slides then opens.  I have a void in a wall and I want to install a 48”x16x4” wall safe but I’d like to put removable pins on the inside of the safe so I can get behind the safe into the void without unscrewing the safe.  Any suggestions? It will probably weigh 100 pounds when full.

Comment: some sort twice co-joined hinge of hinge with thee pins  perhaps. it will probably need to be the full height of the cabinet,

Comment: Why pins and not screws? Pins will likely protrude into the safe so they can be pulled out.  Sounds like one of those hidden gun safes, personally I'd use some truss head screws.

Comment: Youtube : [How To: Install a Single Out-swing **Murphy Door**](https://youtu.be/87S1Oq1ie-c?t=161)

Comment: A sketch and/or photo would sure help your case here...